# Should I use mod or remainder when checking a BigInteger for divisibility?

Tags: java, biginteger

When checking a `BigInteger` `a` for divisibility by some `BigInteger` `b`, I can write either `a.mod(b).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)` or `a.remainder(b).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)`.

Which of the two expressions is more efficient?

**EDIT:** Several people have correctly pointed out that `mod` doesn't accept a negative modulus. Please assume that `b` is positive in your answer.

Comment: Use `remainder` if you just want to check it is nonzero. `mod` just does `remainder` with a little extra calculation on top.

Comment: An implementation detail - OpenJDK's implementation of `mod()` calls `remainder()` under the hood.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between those methods is documented in the Javadoc. From [`mod(m)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod-java.math.BigInteger-):

> This method differs from `remainder` in that it always returns a non-negative BigInteger.

Also, this method throws a [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) if the given argument is negative, which, as per your edit, is not your case. As such, to test for divisibility, there will be no difference between `mod` and `remainder`: when one of them is 0 the other will also be 0. You could just use `remainder` since `mod` can make another calculation that you don't need.

---

To see the difference in action, consider the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(-2);
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
    System.out.println(a.remainder(b)); // prints -2
    System.out.println(a.mod(b)); // prints 1 == -2 (i.e. the remainder) + 3
}
```

This is actually the same difference for primitive `int` `a` and `b` and calculating `a % b` (which behaves like `remainder`) and [`Math.floorMod(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) (which behaves like `mod`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `mod` won't accept moduli `<= 0` !

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the javadocs..

For Mod(BigInteger m):

> Returns a BigInteger whose value is (`this mod m`). This method differs from remainder in that it always returns a *non-negative* BigInteger.

Comment: How does this answer the question which of the two operations is more efficient?

Comment: Also note that I don't care whether the result is positive or negative - I just want to know whether it is `0` or not.

Answer (score 1):

These are different operations. You can see from the JavaDoc that `mod()` is not working with zero or negative arguments. You can find this article helpful: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/modulus-remainder/

Answer (score 0):

They behave differently if `b` is negative. Use whichever operation you intend to use.